# How to copy lists from word to OneNote?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-onenote

I have a multilevel list in word, like this

```
1. abc
    a. abc
    b. abc
2. abc
    a. abc
    b. abc
```

But the list cannot be copied into OneNote as a whole, you can only select part of the text in one line to copy. In other words, you can only copy the text not the list.

Is there a way to copy the list?

Answer (score 1):

Copy your list in Word, right-click on the note you want to add the text to and under *Paste Options*, select *Keep Source Formatting* (first icon with the paintbrush).

Comment: Actually I've tried that. If you only select the "1" and sub-part of the list, excluding the "2" part, it works. If you include the "2" part, nothing shows up.

Comment: Looks like it's a bug, after creating a new page, it works.